# Wordpress with WooCommerce API Multiple Product Upload

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce

Apologies if this may not be in the right place, but I'm really struggling to find (and understand) any information on this and have had no response from the dedicated forum.

I'm running the Flatastic Theme on Wordpress and have WooCommerce running it as a multi-vendor marketplace.

A client of mine wants to upload multiple products at once using API methods. They currently do this with eBay, their Magento site and Google Merchant.

What I want to know is, how easy it to set up my end? If I visit the WooCommerce settings, generate a key for that user and assign the right to read/write, will that suffice or do I need to do more on the backend?

Any help appreciated as I don't just want to give them the keys and assume it will work.

Thanks,
M